# Where to start REST web service in C# or ASP.Net

Tags: c#, rest

I am thinking to start writing some REST web services as a way to provide data. I guess that when my REST web services are available, then some of my web applications and console applications will be able to use REST web service as data service to get, add, update and delete data to databases. In addition to that, I would like to add authentication feature to identify any request.

My question is that where should I start? I saw [Microsoft ADO.Net Data Services](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/bb931106.aspx). Not sure if this is a good start place? Are there any examples available?

Comment: May I ask, out of interest, why you need ReST to simply expose your database? What scenario are you trying to solve? If you just want to expose CRUD data over xml, that's called POX, and has nothing to do with the architectural style ReST.

Comment: one example is that we have a database that is charged by license based on connection calls from machines. Within one machine, there is no limit to make calls but we have to pay for calls from other PCs. In addition to that, network fire-wall is another issue. So I think REST web service may be the best way to resolve the issue. We can make calls to the REST service and let the REST service to make one connection or local calls to db.

Comment: Well then you're not talking about ReST, you're talking about simple http-based xml services. POX != ReST.

Comment: @Murph: This answer was added before the comment system existed.  Please, check post dates before downvoting/commenting.  Or, in future, you can just flag as not an answer, and mods can handle it.  Thanks.

Comment: @Will the question was asked in July '09, this blog post from Jan '09 discusses improvements to the comment system: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/01/new-replies-notification/ by all means mod assertively... but...

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Check out the [REST in WCF MSDN site](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/netframework/cc950529.aspx) and the [starter kit](http://aspnet.codeplex.com/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx?ReleaseId=24644).  Good article [here](http://www.developer.com/net/article.php/3695436) too.

Comment: That first link doesn't talk specifically about C# or .Net at all, it only speaks about REST in general.

Comment: REST in WCF no longer supported - now it points to ASP http://www.asp.net/web-api/tutorials/hands-on-labs/build-restful-apis-with-aspnet-web-api

Answer (score 10):

You may also want to check out **[servicestack.net](http://www.servicestack.net)** An Open Source, cross-platform, high-performance web service framework that lets you develop web services using code-first, strongly-typed DTO's which will automatically (without any configuration) be immediately available on a variety of different endpoints out-of-the-box (i.e. XML, JSON, JSV, SOAP 1.1/1.2).

#### REST, RPC and SOAP out of the box

In addition, your same web services can also be made available via any ReST-ful url of your choice where the preferred serialization format can be specified by your REST client i.e.

- Using the HTTP **Accept:** header
- Appending the preferred format to the query string e.g. **?format=xml**

See the [Nothing but REST!](http://www.servicestack.net/ServiceStack.MovieRest/) web service example for how to develop a complete REST-ful Ajax CRUD app with only **1 page of jQuery** and **1 page of C#**.

A good place to start is the **[Hello World example](http://www.servicestack.net/ServiceStack.Hello/)** to see how to easily add ServiceStack web services to any existing ASP.NET web application.

#### Performance

For the performance conscience, ServiceStack makes an excellent Ajax server as it comes bundled with the [fastest JSON Serializer for .NET](http://www.servicestack.net/mythz_blog/?p=344) (> 3x faster than other JSON Serializers).

Checkout [this live Ajax app](http://www.servicestack.net/RedisAdminUI/AjaxClient/) for a taste (Live demo hosted on Linux/Nginx/MONO).

### Simple Northwind Example

[ServiceStack](http://www.servicestack.net) also makes it easy to create strong-typed frictionless web services where with just the code below is all you need to return a List of Customer POCOs:

```
    public class CustomersService : RestServiceBase<Customers>
    {
            public IDbConnectionFactory DbFactory { get; set; }

            public override object OnGet(Customers request)
            {
              return new CustomersResponse { Customers = DbFactory.Exec(dbCmd =>
                    dbCmd.Select<Customer>()) 
            };
    }
```

With no other config, you can now call the above webservice REST-fully returning all of:

- [XML](http://www.servicestack.net/ServiceStack.Northwind/customers?format=xml)
- [JSON](http://www.servicestack.net/ServiceStack.Northwind/customers?format=json)
- [CSV](http://www.servicestack.net/ServiceStack.Northwind/customers?format=csv)
- [HTML](http://www.servicestack.net/ServiceStack.Northwind/customers?format=html)
- [JSV](http://www.servicestack.net/ServiceStack.Northwind/customers?format=jsv)
- [SOAP](http://www.servicestack.net/ServiceStack.Hello/soap12/metadata?op=Hello)

### Accessing web services on the client

You can call the above web service re-using the same DTOs that your web services were defined with (i.e. no code-gen is required) using your preferred generic ServiceClient (i.e Json, Xml, etc). This allows you to call your web services using a strong-typed API with just 1 Line of code:

**C# Sync Example**

```
IServiceClient client = new JsonServiceClient("http://host/service");
var customers = client.Send<CustomersResponse>(new Customers());
```

And since your web services are also REST services, it works seamlessly with JavaScript ajax clients, e.g:

**Using jQuery**

```
$.getJSON("http://host/service", function(r) { alert(r.Customers.length); });
```

Answer (score 7):

ASP.NET Web API is now the Microsoft framework for creating RESTful services.

http://www.asp.net/web-api

Comment: Not the only framework. If you still need the features of WCF (like a single service with both REST and SOAP endpoints), then WCF is the way to go.

Answer (score 4):

If you are new to REST in the .net world then start with [OpenRasta](http://trac.caffeine-it.com/openrasta).  The other Microsoft solutions can do REST if you work hard at it but they will guide you down a route where you will most likely end up with POD(Plain old data) over HTTP.  That is not what REST is all about.  If that's all you want then that's cool too, but it is not REST.

Comment: I didn't know OpenRasta has so many cool features. And I was almost sure it is some kind of framework for building ASP.NET MVC websites. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

- If you're going WCF, the WCF REST Starter Kit that JP referred to is a great place to start.
- Omar Al Zabir [provides a pretty good example](http://msmvps.com/blogs/omar/archive/2008/10/03/create-rest-api-using-asp-net-mvc-that-speaks-both-json-and-plain-xml.aspx) of using ASP.NET MVC to provide RESTful services that are fluent in both XML and JSON
- You can also go the ADO.NET Data Services route you suggested. These services are built on top of the WCF stack.

I've never stumbled across any really good guidance on how to select between these options. In ASP.NET MVC you take on the majority of the plumbing burden but also have maximal control. Straight RESTful WCF is the happy middle ground although WCF tends to want to have things done its way. ADO.NET Data Services are pretty magical with the downside of buying fully into a given approach to generating these services and losing more flexibility.

There are a couple of good books you can read on the topic of RESTful services with .NET. Both O'Reilly and Microsoft Press have recently released books on this topic. Perhaps the most important advice I can provide you is to consume and understand several open RESTful services (e.g. Twitter, Amazon, Flickr) to understand the design decisions that went into creating the services. User provisioning, authentication mechanism, and supported content types (e.g. JSON, XML, RSS/ATOM) are some of the decisions that you can observe in action to aid you in your path to creating your service API.