# Comparable Frameworks .NET and JAVA (Persistence / Webservice / Marshalling)

Tags: java, .net, web-services, frameworks, persistence

Are there any .Net frameworks comparable with the follwing JAVA framworks?

**JPA 2.0** persistence-framework (EclipseLink or OpenJPA implementations)
**jersey framework** (for REST-webservices)
**gson framework** (json marshalling library)

And is there any reason to favor Java or .Net (related to the frameworks above)?

Comment: - **JPA** Dupe question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2756307/what-is-the-equivalent-of-jpa-in-net
- **gson** Dupe question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1474377/json-library-for-c
- **jersey** I don't know enough about the .NET REST facilities or library to answer this, but I bet there's a near-dupe!  Maybe this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1157141/where-to-start-rest-web-service-in-c-or-asp-net

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See my comment on the original question for why the equivalent library questions are dupes.

At this point, I'd select between Java and .NET because of IT requirements, and your development experience, not because of libraries.  OS support and .NET framework/Java installation (for customers and/or your hosting company) are the key blocking issues.

There are a huge amount of great libraries for both, and you'll just have to dig into one of them before you figure out what's missing, and whether you should care for your project.