# call subroutines via URL across local network?

Tags: .net, windows, vb.net, winforms

I'm writing a program in Visual Basic .NET to perform actions on a PC on my local network.

I'm looking basically for some sort of extremely simple solution to allow me to:

- call subroutines/functions from other machines on the network via their web browsers
- post arguments into the url if possible (see optimistic example below)
- allow a response string of html to be sent (see example again)

**Example:**
entering `http://192.168.1.72/function/argument1/argument2` would run the 'function' sub/function within my winforms application application on that (locally networked) machine, and pass through argument1 and argument2 (if they were included), then return a response page/string to the requesting browser as feedback

Could anyone point me in the way of a way to do this? I'm looking for something fairly simple, but reliable because it may end up running around the clock

Comment: You essentially want to develop a [REST web service](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1157141/1968) and make that web service communicate with your WinForms application via [inter-process communication](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inter-process_communication).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I'm looking for something fairly simple, but reliable because it may end up running around the clock

I think simpliest way would be using the [WebServiceHost](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.web.webservicehost.aspx) class of WCF:

```
[ServiceContract]
public class MyService
{
    [OperationContract, WebGet(UriTemplate = "/function/{argument1}/{argument2}")]
    public string AMethod(string argument1, string argument2)
    {
        return argument1 + " " + argument2;
    }
}
```

Put this lines to formload(or any other entry point) of your application,

```
var wsh = new WebServiceHost(typeof(MyService), new Uri("http://0.0.0.0/MyService"));
wsh.Open();
```

and call like `http://192.168.1.72/Myservice/function/a/b` from your browser. That is all.

***----Full Working Code----***

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.ServiceModel.Web;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
        {
            var wsh = new WebServiceHost(typeof(MyService), new Uri("http://0.0.0.0/MyService"));
            wsh.Open();
        }
    }

    [ServiceContract]
    public class MyService
    {
        [OperationContract, WebGet(UriTemplate = "/function/{argument1}/{argument2}")]
        public string AMethod(string argument1, string argument2)
        {
            return argument1 + " " + argument2;
        }

        ///******** EDIT ********
        ///
        [OperationContract, WebGet(UriTemplate = "/function2/{argument1}/{argument2}")]
        public Stream F2(string argument1, string argument2)
        {
            return ToHtml("<html><h1>" + argument1 + " " + argument2 + "</h1></HtmlDocument>");
        }

        static Stream ToHtml(string result)
        {
            var data = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(result);

            WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse.ContentType = "text/html; charset=utf-8";
            WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse.ContentLength = data.Length;

            return new MemoryStream(data);
        }
        ///END OF EDIT
    }
}
```

### EDIT

> *is it possible to determine the IP address the request is coming from?*

```
var m = OperationContext.Current
        .IncomingMessageProperties[RemoteEndpointMessageProperty.Name] as RemoteEndpointMessageProperty;

var address = m.Address;
```

> *any way to make the {arguments} optional?*

Just remove the `UriTemplate` parameter from `WebGet` attribute. Then your url will be as

```
http://1192.168.1.72/MyService/AMethod?argument1=aaaa&argument2=bbb
```

If you want to make argument2 optional for ex, call as

```
http://1192.168.1.72/MyService/AMethod?argument1=aaaa
```

and argument2 will get the default value in your method.

Comment: Thank you, this works a charm. Had a little trouble in the beginning as I'm running Windows in Parallels' on a Mac, network wasn't behaving nicely. But running on a windows maching, it works gorgeously. Thanks

Comment: Is it possible to have it return a string of HTML or my own XML to be displayed in the browser rather than text wrapped in microsoft's XML? Rather than: http://pastebin.com/HdPyne9u -- Optimally, I'd like to be able to return both custom XML data and HTML pages to be rendered in browser?

Comment: @rabbitt See the edit in my answer. Using `Stream` you can return any result (text,xml,json,image etc.). Just don't forget to set the correct *content-type*. ie (`text/html` for html)

Comment: @14V Ahh thank you, you've been so helpful. I don't mean to bother you, but is it possible to determine the IP address the request is coming from? Also any way to make the {arguments} optional? E.g. you don't have to include them for it still to process 'function' in your above code sample.

Comment: @14V I promise this is the last add-on question, *nervous laugh*, Is there a way to add simple authentication to this service? E.g. when you go to your router portal and it prompts for credentials (username, password). The same type of credentials you can pass through to a HttpWebRequest in a client program?

Answer (score 1):

All you need here is some form of web service. You may want to use a REST web service using [ASP.NET Web API](http://www.asp.net/web-api).

A separate Inter-process communication mechanism would not be necessary.