# Accessing Directory Structure off Remote Machine

Tags: c#, architecture

I am working on application, which is divided in Client and Server part. Basically Server reads the TASK Database table, and perform the requested task and update database once complete. On other hand Client create Task entry as user desire.

Now some task are to read files which will be presented on Server machine, however we need Client to locate those files. For this I need to show directory structure of Server machine to client. So they can navigate to Folder structure and select relevant folder and files as per requirement. Also, at one stage we need Client to able to download the Files from Remote server.

On Server end we currently have Windows Service as it is mainly a background work it needs to perform and on client end I am using WPF based GUI.

Now, I am not sure what method I should use to access folder structure and to allow download of file. I have two options as I think

1. I create a TCP/IP Connection between my Client machine and Server machine. Then Server machine will pass Directory Structure as JSON To client and I show it on Custom build Tree View.
2. I create a Web service on Client end, and then consume that web service at client.

I can definiately use either of method to download files if I Can access folder structure. Now I find some drawback on either method.

1. on TCP/IP connection I have to maintain the connection between client and server which is otherwise not required as both application work independently. Infact with it's current architecture we can use application from outside domain or LAN.

With #2 solution, I am not willing to use default web server, as I am not sure if server are used for other parts in organization. So, I want to club this webservice with my Windows Service in background, is it possible if so, how? This give me fix address to access the service as well. But if I build on general webservice then I fear how I do the Directory structure reading does IIS or Apache allow reading of complete file structure?

Which solution is better and of course easy to code :) and maintain.

Comment: Maybe a 3rd way? WCF? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15852859/call-subroutines-via-url-across-local-network

Comment: Well that is basically second way I refer a Web service. WCF need web server only. :). Also for my need I think setting up WCF in core is heavy way of doing it, a simple single page JSON base webpage can do the same thing. But seems that is best solution for now.

Comment: *Sumit Gupta*, `I think setting up WCF in core is heavy way of doing it`. Did you see the working code there. 10-20 lines of code to get it up and running. No config file etc. And it works with json.

Comment: I realise I didn't fully understand 3rd option on second view. Can I ask how we can access that Webservice from local browser. I didn't see any part been hosted on Default web server, or attachment to port. I am currently trying to run it to see, but if you can explain it further is great help. Thanks.

Comment: Sumit Gupta, It is a self-hosted WCF service. No need for IIS etc.. Just create an WindowsFormsApplication and run it. url will be `http://localhost/Myservice/function/a/b`. The `WebServiceHost` class handles all of attachments, port issues etc.(By using the Uri passed to it)

Comment: As expected I am not sure on what URL I can access that service host. I try to run it as http://localhost/MyService/... but it doesn't found  server, [at this point I realise I do not have IIS installed on my machine, so I install it] as soon as I Install IIS and restart program it give 404, as Myservice is not present under IIS. So where and how you bind it for web/browser access ? Thanks

Comment: Sumit, **No need for IIS** but It may require you `run as administrator`. And I posted the real url in my previous comment.

Comment: I think your solutions seems promising now, I am able to get it working. I got question: How can I make it to bind to different port than 80. Thanks.

Comment: never mind I found it. I have to change the var wsh = new WebServiceHost(typeof(MyService), new Uri("http://0.0.0.0:8000/MyService")); to include port I want it to host. This is really great.