# How to develop REST server with C# on Windows Compact 7?

Tags: c#, rest, visual-studio-2008, windows-embedded-compact

I want to develop the web service with C# on Windows Compact7. But it cannot use like `"System.ServiceModel.Web"`.

How can I develop REST Web service with C# on Windows Compact7? I need to make it with scratch?

Thanks.

Comment: if `System.ServiceModel.Web` can not be used, most probably [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15852859/call-subroutines-via-url-across-local-network) would not work but may be [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10017564/url-mapping-with-c-sharp-httplistener)?

Comment: Is there other method to make REST web service with C#?