# Returing a json string using a webservice in c#.net

Tags: c#, .net, web-services

I developed an androidapp communicating with a .NET web service using soap messages. But I don't know how to write a web service which returns a json string that will be used to return some values to the android app. 

Any help will be greatly appreciated.


 Thankz

Comment: Web Service would be too much. Take look at ASP.NET Web API http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15852859/call-subroutines-via-url-across-local-network

Comment: @RadimKöhler : Thankz for the link...I will look into it. But why you say web service is too much, can I know the reason please ?

Comment: You need the JSON. Web Services do encapsulate all the stuff in XML (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_Services_Description_Language - WSDL). The Web API will directly return JSON