# How to build web service/web api with optional parameters in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services

I'm building a web API using web service.
Users may use it like this:
`http://www.example.com/example.asmx/hello?param1=str&param2=str`

or:

`http://www.example.com/example.asmx/hello?param1=str` .

I want to make param1 required while param2 optional.But my code below always throws an exception that says missing values for parameters when I try to call `http://www.example.com/example.asmx/hello?param1=str`. It works fine with `http://www.example.com/example.asmx/hello?param1=str&param2=str`.

```
[WebMethod]
public string hello(int param1, int param2 = 0)
{
    return "hello!";
}
```

Is there any way to fix it? If not, what techniques can I use to build a web API that accept optional parameters which is very common in public APIs. I'm a newbie so I don't know if web service is a good choice for building web APIs. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15852859/call-subroutines-via-url-across-local-network

Comment: @l4V Thanks! Seems I need to learn something about WCF. I'll give it a try and see if it works.

Comment: You may want to think about using ASP.NET Web API. I'm pretty sure it handles that case correctly and it's designed specifically for building Web APIs.

Comment: @YoussefMoussaoui I'll google something about ASP.NET Web API, thanks for your help.

Comment: @YoussefMoussaoui Thanks for your help! I've tried Web API and it works like a charm! That's exactly what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

basically you cant do that.

i suggest you to read this article first:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jmstall/archive/2012/04/16/how-webapi-does-parameter-binding.aspx

it explains pretty well how parameters are bound.

Comment: I don't think he's using Web API at all.

Comment: regarding to sample uri's, then yes, i agree.

Answer (score 0):

have you considered to use [params](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w5zay9db%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) which works within applications (wpf / winforms).

```
    // not tested
    [WebMethod]
    public string hello(params int[] list)
    {
        string s = "Hello\n";
        // do some stuff with your ints
        for ( int i = 0 ; i < list.Length ; i++ )
          s += list[i] + "\n" ;

        return s;
    }
```

Comment: well,parameters here are name/value pair. Say, `1http://www.example.com/example.asmx/hello?userid=a1b2&count=5`. Both the paremeter name and parameter value are needed. I suppose your method doesn't support name/value type parameters.

Answer (score 0):

The problem probably is that for web method this parameter is required. Maybe this will help.

In accordance with [MinOccurs Attribute Binding Support](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zds0b35c(v=vs.80).aspx#Anchor_2) and [Default Attribute Binding Support](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8d1es9ye(v=vs.80).aspx#Anchor_3):

1. Value type accompanied by a public bool field that uses the Specified naming convention described previously under Translating XSD to source - minOccurs value of output `<element>` element 0.

   ```
   [WebMethod]
   public SomeResult SomeMethod(bool optionalParam, [XmlIgnore] bool optionalParamSpecified)
   ```

   result:

   ```
   <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="optionalParam" type="s:boolean" />
   ```
2. Value type with a default value specified via a System.Component.DefaultValueAttribute - minOccurs value of output `<element>` element 0. In the `<element>` element, the default value is also specified via the default XML attribute.

   ```
   [WebMethod]
   public SomeResult SomeMethod([DefaultValue(true)] bool optionalParam)
   ```

   result:

   ```
   <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" default="true" name="optionalParam" type="s:boolean" />
   ```