# Can ASP.NET Web API methods be called from a Windows CE app / CF 3.5?

Tags: rest, .net-3.5, asp.net-web-api, compact-framework, windows-ce

We were thinking about doing something like WCF / REST - I think the techn[ique,ology] was called ADO.NET Data Services in VS 2008 / .NET 3.5 - anyway, something like a RESTful receiving and transmitting of data from a CF 3.5 app and a desktop .NET 4 app to simplify the client / Windows CE app so that it simply sends and receives XML or JSON data, rather than connecting to a remote database or so.

However, according to [Where to start REST web service in C# or ASP.Net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1157141/where-to-start-rest-web-service-in-c-sharp-or-asp-net):

"REST in WCF no longer supported - now it points to ASP"

From the same link:

"ASP.NET Web API is now the Microsoft framework for creating RESTful services.
http://www.asp.net/web-api"

Okay, I think we can do that (WebAPI) - the plan is to host the server/service in IIS; however: Can ASP.NET Web API methods be called from CF 3.5? Does anybody have examples of such?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at Microsoft's article [Calling WCF Services](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc164240.aspx#S7).

To create your service, you are going to need to [Power Toys for .NET Compact Framework 3.5](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=13442), then turn around after installing that to [Download the New NetCFSvcUtil](http://download.microsoft.com/download/6/2/0/6205ED05-E435-44FC-AA82-B763CA5F8B1A/NetCFSvcUtil.exe) (that is a direct download).

I've created Batch files that I store in my `Services` folder of my Windows Mobile Project (that way, I can't lose them). The batch file is like this:

** create.bat **

```
NetCFSvcUtil.exe /l:cs /o:Employee.cs /cb:ServiceModelBase http://cpweb2/mainframe/AcpEmployee.svc?wsdl
pause
NetCFSvcUtil.exe /l:cs /o:Packout.cs /cb:ServiceModelBase http://cpweb2/mainframe/AcpPackout.svc?wsdl
pause
```

That creates 2 Proxy files for me: One for Employees and one for my Packout service. They both create the same base file, ServiceModelBase, which is just a way for services to throw exceptions.

Adding the `pause` between steps enables you to read any error messages that are thrown up on the screen before running the next command.

Comment: You don't need any of this if you are going to do REST services. WCF has a ton of overhead that isn't necessary for REST calls. And since you are just doing a REST client in CF, it would be so much less overhead to bypass all this WCF tech. If you like cans of worms by all means go to WCF. I've done WCF services and clients for over 5 years and just had headache after headache. Just one poorly set configuration in either the client or service config file and you are dead in the water. Just my $.02

Comment: I'm not a fan of worms in cans, unless freeze dried, pulverized, and used in a one part per thousand mixture with chocolate as the base ingredient. Even then, I can take them or leave them. So, I did find the HttpWebRequest freely available in my 3.5 project, so hopefully that will work just dandy.

Comment: No worries, based on your marked answer, I thought you were going the WCF route.

Answer (score 3):

As long as CF 3.5 can make http requests, then you should be able to make rest calls. Look for HttpWebRequest in CF.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa446517.aspx